# netbeans create .new file instead of overwrite it

Tags: ftp, netbeans-8

I'm tring to work on php project using NetBeans v8.1 with remote server connection.
I've tried active mode but when saving the file it gives me this error:
I won't open a connection to 192.168.1.100 (only to 197.133.xxx.xx)
So I changed the connection mode to passive mode.
When I try to save the file to upload, a new file created on the server directory with .new extension (ex. index.php.new) and it's empty, and Netbeans gives me this error:
Upload files on save failed.
For the information: My FTP encryption: "Explicit  FTP using TLS"
And when I Press on "Test Connection", it gives me "connection succeeded"
[Screenshot of the connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87P3u.jpg)

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and it appears to be a server communication issue using TLS in passive mode.

Try ticking the box "Encrypt Only Authentication Process" -  did the trick for me :)